# Stripe Angular Ionic Application - Payment Creation

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

I am creating a [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) payment system, and am having difficulty making this integrated code functional. The code was pulled [from here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js#L28-L55). What I am trying to do is create a database reference to the specific user ID (uid) of the user, since the `createStripeCharge` waits for a `write event` to occur to something like `/stripe_customers/XCXaweADowefj/charges/QC123XYZ`. I'm not sure, but perhaps my issue is that I am incorrectly referencing the customer. If you have any ideas or feedback about how I can make this function correctly I greatly appreciate it!

**The Trigger (this causes the Cloud Function to work):**

```
payByStripe(amount,email,userId, token): firebase.database.Reference {
  return firebase.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${userId}/charges/`).push({
    amount:amount,
    email:email,
    token:token
  });    
}
```

**Cloud Function:**

```
exports.createStripeCharge = functions.database.ref('/stripe_customers/{userId}/charges/{id}').onWrite(event => {
  const val = event.data.val();
  if (val === null || val.id || val.error) return null;
  return admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${event.params.userId}/customer_id`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
    return snapshot.val();
  }).then(customer => {
    const amount = val.amount;
    const idempotency_key = event.params.id;
    let charge = {amount, currency, customer};
    if (val.source !== null) charge.source = val.source;
    return stripe.charges.create(charge, {idempotency_key});
  }).then(response => {
      return event.data.adminRef.set(response);
    }, error => {
      return event.data.adminRef.child('error').set(userFacingMessage(error)).then(() => {
        return reportError(error, {user: event.params.userId});
      });
    }
  );
});
```

Currently, the database is creating the stripe customers, but the charge doesn't go through, with error message `"You have passed a blank string for 'customer'. You should remove the 'customer' parameter from your request or supply a non-blank value."`

**Update is I've been iterating on this. Tried the following:**

```
firebase.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${userId}/charges/`).push({
  amount:amount,
  email:email,
  token:token,
  customer: userId
});
```

&&

```
firebase.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${userId}/charges/`).push({
  amount:amount,
  email:email,
  token:token,
  customer_id:{
    customer: userId
  }
});
```

And still getting "You have passed a blank string for 'customer'. You should remove the 'customer' parameter from your request or supply a non-blank value."

Comment: if `email` is a valid email in your write to `/stripe_customers/${email}/charges`, the write should fail: `'.'` is not allowed in a firebase key

Comment: @VonD why would it fail? What would you suggest instead?

Comment: the `'.'` character is not allowed to be part of a key (see the note here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree) you could use some user id instead

Comment: @VonD good call - I've adjusted the question a little - thanks!

Comment: you're welcome. How is `/stripe_customers/$userId/customer_id` written to in the first place ? Stripe complains that it is a blank string.

Comment: @VonD is customer_id a key?

Comment: yes, you seem to expect the document at the `/stripe_customers/$userId` path to have the following structure: `{customerId: someValue, charges: {}}`, and `customerId` seems to be either `''` or `null`